# Is there a way to source cron jobs from a file

Tags: linux, cron

One of our servers has around 20-25 different cron jobs scheduled on it.
Usually, we periodically check-in the cron jobs to a file in the repo using `crontab -l > cron.jobs`

While bringing up a new server, which is a replica of the previous server (in terms of OS and deployed code base), is it possible to source the cron jobs for the new server from a file containing valid cron jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a file name is given as the sole argument to the `crontab` command, it is used to replace the current crontab:

```
crontab -l > cron.jobs
crontab cron.jobs
```

Alternately, feed the file through stdin:

```
crontab < cron.jobs
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

> crontab < cron.jobs

on new server. The jobs in `cron.jobs` becomes new jobs replacing the installed jobs. So better take a back-up of existing cron jobs before replacing,

> crontab -l > cron.jobs.bkp

Comment: Or just `crontab cron.jobs`; the `crontab` command can read its input either from `stdin` or from a named file. (The former means that if you accidentally type `crontab` with no arguments, you should type control-C; if you type control-D, you'll clear your existing crontab.)